# extract by terminal the Darwin version

Tags: terminal, macos, versions, darwin

I want to know how extract by terminal the Darwin version.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Sierra#Releases

For macOS Sierra `10.12.3` is **16.4.0** for `10.12.6` is **16.7.0**.

Now, I want to create:

```
--build=x86_64-apple-darwin$(uname -r)
```

Is it possible obtain this complete value?

```
x86_64-apple-darwin16.4.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is very simple using `uname` with the r option.

```
uname -r
```

and

```
sysctl -n kern.osrelease
```

would give you the same results.